# How to remove all `iframe` tags that are only in the current webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, iframe, ecmascript-2016

I have a webpage that has various `iframe` tags.

I want to remove a certain `iframe` that has visible content on that webpage but I couldn't find a selector for it, so I thought deleting all iframes would help:

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  iframes[i].remove();
}
```

Yet, deleting all `iframe` tags brought another problem:

Each time I click on links aimed to open a modal (a popup), I get **blank popups**.

Seems that by deleting all `iframe` tags in my webpage, I've deleted them in other webpages appearing as modals or "sub-webpages", for my webpage.

How to remove all `iframe` tags that are only in the current webpage?

### Update

I would have preferred an all vanilla way.

Comment: so you have all your pages in same document? if so you should have maybe class that indicate current page, if so you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.current-page iframe');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expression that is used by jQuery to test if element is visible:

```
function isVisible(elem) {
    return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length);
}

var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  if (isVisible(iframes[i])) {
    iframes[i].remove();
  }
}
```